# Logic-App name max length incorrect?

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, azure-logic-apps

Maybe I'm missing something here but:

According to the Azure Portal the max length of Logic-App names is 64.

Logic app name example:

"This-is-a-test-name-for-logic-app-to-see-length"

The length of this string is 47, which should be fine. But when creating it I get an error:

"*The provided the distribution name Microsoft.Empty Workflow-This-is-a-test-name-for-logic-app-to-see-length has a length of 71, which is longer than the 64 limit..*"

It seems like the string "*Microsoft.Empty Workflow-*" gets added before the logic-app name, meaning that the actual max length is 40?

Don't know if this is a bug or something that you can work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is in fact a bug in the create logic app experience. Thanks for raising this issue. Will update here once it is resolved.

Note that when the logic app is created, its name will correspond exactly to the name that you enter on the 'Create logic app' blade. The placeholder string that you see only affects name length validation.

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer. Then i'll be waiting for a fix =)

Comment: @viktorh, the issues has been resolved as of a couple of days ago, so names of up to 80 characters should now be accepted.

Comment: Thats great! Thanks alot.